# Constructive way to optimally cover a compact subset of Euclidean space

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, discrete-geometry, constructive-mathematics

Let, $(X,d)$ be a simply connected compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with non-empty interiorn, let $d$ denote the Euclidean metric, and let $\varepsilon>0$.  Is there a way to iteratively select points $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that

1. $
   \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{\operatorname{Ball}(x_i,\varepsilon)} = X
   $
2. There does not exist any $n'<n$ and some $x_1',\dots,x_{n'}'\in X$ such that $
   \bigcup_{i=1}^{n'} \overline{\operatorname{Ball}(x_i',\varepsilon)} = X?
   $
3. The algorithm used to generate $x_1,\dots,x_n$ terminates in polynomial time.

Is there an algorithm for obtaining $x_{\cdot}$ and satisfying conditions 1-3?

Comment: For question 1, I think you need to explain how you have "access" to the points of $X$, i.e. how $X$ is described, since in total abstraction we don't know the "names" of any points of an unknown metric space. The existence of a covering by balls is clear by compactness, so to find a "way to select" one seems to require a "way" of naming points.

Comment: @BenMcKay For the moment, I can assume that $X$ is a topological manifold and I know a finite number of charts (explicitly) to $X$.

Comment: the first question has an affirmative answer under all of the most usual constructive definitions of compact. in fact in the definition of compact equalling "complete and totally bounded" the property of question 1 is the same as the totally bounded part. question 2 is a bit trickier but i believe that it has an affirmative answer for all but countably many $\epsilon$.

Comment: so question 1 can be seen as being part of the definition or an easy consequence of such, question 2 involves a procedure which for certain epsilon might not terminate. there is however another procedure to enumerate all such epsilon.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk I simplified the situation to a simply connected compact in Euclidean space.